# $\frac{Spin(2n-1)\times Spin(2n+1)}{{\mathbf{Z}/2}}\subset SO(4n)?$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, spin-geometry

Is the following statement true?
$$\frac{Spin(2n-1)\times Spin(2n+1)}{{\mathbf{Z}/2}}\subset SO(4n)? \tag{1}$$

- For $n=1$, $SU(2)\subset SO(4)$ true.
- For $n=2$, $\frac{Spin(3)\times Spin(5)}{{\mathbf{Z}/2}}\subset SO(8)$ is true according to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4161519/955245.
- How about $n \geq 3$ in general?

The eq(1) is motivated by the fact that the center of $Z(Spin(2n+1))=Z(Spin(2n-1))=\mathbf{Z}/2$ and $Z(SO(4n))=\mathbf{Z}/2$.

p.s. In contrast, it is easy to know that
$\frac{Spin(n)\times Spin(m)}{{\mathbf{Z}/2}}\subset Spin(n+m)$ and $SO(n) \times SO(m)\subset SO(n+m)$ are both true.

Comment: You have now asked at least 4 questions about which Lie groups contain which copies of other Lie groups.  Why not spend some time learning the necessary representation theory to answer these questions on your own?  But to be more direclty helpful:  here's the proof that you don't have such a subgroup when $n=3$:  A $12$-dim real representations of $Spin(5)\times Spin(7)$ are sums of tensor products of irreducibles where each summand is real or paired with its complex conjugate.   Since we want the ineffective kernel to be $\mathbb{Z}/2$ (which I assume is diagonally embedded)...

Comment: It follows that the rep, when restricted to both factors, must be injective.  From the Weyl dimension formula, the only non-trivial reps of $Spin(7)$ of dim $<12$ are the standard rep on $\mathbb{R}^7$ and the spin rep on $\mathbb{R}^8$, so injectivity forces us to use the spin rep.  Since $2\cdot 8 > 12$, the summand of the rep using the spin rep must have the form $trivial\otimes spin$.  The complementary rep (which must be injective on $Spin(5)$, has dimension 4.  But $Spin(5)$ has a unique non-trivial rep of dim $\leq 4$, so we cannot find a complementary rep.

Comment: Once you understand this proof, you should be able to show non-existence for $n\geq 4$ using a similar, but easier approach.

Comment: Thanks - the problem is that I am an engineer major (bachelor) - I would love to know which math textbooks or notes that you recommend me to go through -- I will! hope to show you I am a quick learner! thank you!

Comment: I learned everything I know from a combination of Fulton and Harris's "Representation Theory" book, as well as these online notes:  http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/math650/LieGroupsReps.pdf  (I am a student of Ziller and was in one of the classes where those notes were taken).  Good luck!

Comment: many thanks! for the refs