# Restriction on $n$ for ${Spin(n)\times Spin(n+2)} \subset Spin(2n+2) $ to be true

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, spin-geometry

We know that

$$SO(n) \times SO(m)\subset SO(n+m) \tag{1}$$

$$\frac{Spin(n)\times Spin(m)}{{\mathbf{Z}/2}}\subset Spin(n+m) \tag{2}$$

are both true.

Eq (1) is true for the obvious reason. Eq (2) can be interpret as mod out the common ${\mathbf{Z}/2}$ center subgroup of $Spin(n)\times Spin(m)$.
Then Eq (2) mod 2 gives rise to Eq (1). So this makes sense.

I wanted to prove that whether
$${Spin(n)\times Spin(n+2)} \subset Spin(2n+2) \tag{3}$$
may be true for certain cases, or may be false in other cases. Are there general statements that we can prove, for $n\geq 2$?

Here is what I know so far:

1. $n=m-2=2$, $Spin(2)\times Spin(4) = U(1)\times SU(2)\times SU(2)  \subset Spin(6)=SU(4)$ seems true if we choose a proper $U(1)$.
2. $n=m-2=3$, $Spin(3)\times Spin(5) =  SU(2)\times Spin(5)  \subset Spin(8)$ seems true.
   Because $\frac{Spin(3)\times Spin(5)}{{\mathbf{Z}/2}}\subset SO(8)$ is true according to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4161519/955245, so we double cover both sides and we get $Spin(3)\times Spin(5) \subset Spin(8)$.
3. Can we keep going to prove $Spin(n)\times Spin(n+2)  \subset Spin(2n+2)$ for $n=4$ and so on? Or is there a constraint or counter example which $n$ the equality fails?

Comment: Regarding point 2. Just because $H$ embeds in $G$, and both $H$ and $G$ have double covers, does not automatically imply that $2.H$ embeds in $2.G$ with centres coinciding.

Comment: But I think ()×()/2⊂(+)(2) is true. Yes? thanks

Comment: I'd have to check, as I cannot remember off the top of my head. My point is that the 'So' part of your statement doesn't hold in general, in fact, most of the time.

Comment: thanks, it will be great to know when does it hold "restriction on $n$" - when will it be true?

Comment: I would advise against writing things like $\frac{Spin(n)\times Spin(m)}{{\mathbf{Z}/2}}\subset Spin(n+m)$. This is not literally true (an element of the first group is not an element of the second). What you mean is that there is an embedding from the first into the second (alternatively, there is a subgroup of the second which is isomorphic to the first as abstract groups). In general, the embedding is not unique and depending on the question you're asking, which embedding you're using may have an impact on the answer.

Comment: I wrote (()×())//2⊂(+) to mean that the /2 is the common Normal subgroup of () and (), that is quotient out in (()×()) to become  (()×())//2. Is this clear then?

Comment: Thank you for comment!

Comment: I know exactly what you meant, but my comment still stands. It is literally a false statement.